# Explanation of flux behavior on RESTful API in Spring

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am working on understanding Spring's Webflux and reactive APIs, and would appreciate an explanation of the difference in behavior of a flux I see when a REST endpoint is declared using annotations vice a route/handler.

What I am seeing is that a flux (stream?) is executing when obtained via a REST endpoint defined via annotations, but not from a REST endpoint defined using route/handler semantics.

Can anyone explain the difference in observed behavior? Code and console output provided below...

Note: The commented code in *DemoRequestHandler.getOddIntsMult()* will cause the flux to execute and iterate over the contained integers to find/return the odd values. I imagine my real question is "why is the *subscribe()* required in one instance and not the other?"

Annotated REST controller...

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

@RestController
public class DemoFluxController {

    @RequestMapping(method=GET, value="/v1/fluxMult")
    public Flux<Integer> getMultFlux() {
        System.out.println("DEBUG -> FluxController.getMultFlux()");
        return DemoFlux.getOddInts(DemoFlux.multIntFlux);
    }
}
```

Test class used to return a flux with odd integers...

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class DemoFlux {

    public static Flux<Integer> multIntFlux = Flux.range(1, 20);

    private static boolean isOdd(Integer intVal) {
        System.out.printf("DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( %d )%n", intVal);
        return intVal % 2 != 0;
    }

    public static Flux<Integer> getOddInts(Flux<Integer> intFlux) {
        return intFlux.filter(DemoFlux::isOdd);
    }
}
```

Router implementation declaring an alternate REST endpoint...

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

@Configuration
public class DemoRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(DemoRequestHandler requestHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/v2/fluxMult")
                          .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), requestHandler::getOddIntsMult);
    }
}
```

Request handler associated with route for REST endpoint.

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class DemoRequestHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getOddIntsMult(ServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("DEBYG -> DemoRequestHandler.getOddIntsMult()");

        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(DemoFlux.getOddInts(DemoFlux.multIntFlux)));
//                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(DemoFlux.getOddInts(DemoFlux.multIntFlux).subscribe()));
    }
}
```

Console output from run. Note the different behavior depending on which REST endpoint is accessed...

```
DEBUG -> DemoFluxController.getMultFlux()
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.getOddInts()
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 1 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 2 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 3 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 4 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 5 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 6 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 7 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 8 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 9 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 10 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 11 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 12 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 13 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 14 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 15 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 16 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 17 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 18 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 19 )
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.isOdd( 20 )

DEBUG -> DemoRequestHandler.getOddIntsMult()
DEBUG -> DemoFlux.getOddInts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they don't act the same because you have not coded them the same.

One of the most common misstakes people do when working with webflux/reactive programming is that they subscribe in the middle of their applications because they want or need the concrete value for something.

WebFlux/reactive programming is basically that we declare a chain of events that we wish for to happen when someone subscribes. And in this case it is when the client subscribes. So it's really good of you to sense that something is wrong, because there is!

Your problem is here:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getOddIntsMult(ServerRequest request) {
    System.out.println("DEBYG -> DemoRequestHandler.getOddIntsMult()");

    return ServerResponse.ok()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(              // This body inserter here
            DemoFlux.getOddInts(DemoFlux.multIntFlux)));
}
```

What happens is that the BodyInserter expects a concrete value, and if you look into the source code for it you can see that a body inserter wraps the body in a mono. So what you are doing is that it wraps the `Flux` in a `Mono` so what you essentially get is a `Mono<Flux<Integer>>`.

After you have worked a while with webflux you can tell that this is the case when you get something like:

```
{
    "disposed": true,
    "scanAvailable": true
}
```

Then you know you are getting a wrapped mono/flux and you missed a flatmap somewhere.

If you rewrite it and remove the `BodyInserter` it will work as expected.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getOddIntsMult(ServerRequest request) {
    System.out.println("DEBYG -> DemoRequestHandler.getOddIntsMult()");

    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(DemoFlux.getOddInts(DemoFlux.multIntFlux), Integer.class);                
}
```

So there is no difference, your `@RequestMapping(method=GET, value="/v1/fluxMult")` does not use the `DemoRequestHandler` hence you get different results.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, and gave me more insight into WebFlux/reactive. Also, the return value you referenced (i.e., "disposed": true,...) is exactly what I was seeing.

Comment: No worries, glad i could help. Its a bit tricky at first but you get into the functional way of thinking after a while.